# (0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this error - can you tell me what is wrong? Maybe its the dependency ?

> (0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase)(_firebase.default, rrfConfig)', '(0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase)' is undefined)

Here is my package.json. I'm pretty new to react. It's a boilerplate I found on github :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.5.0",
    "@expo/samples": "3.0.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.2",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^3.0.9",
    "jest-expo": "33.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  }
```

Comment: Adde the code where you are using the package and executing the function

Comment: (0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase)(_firebase.default, rrfConfig)', '(0, _reactReduxFirebase.reactReduxFirebase)' is undefined)

<unknown>
    index.js:34:23
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    App.js:8
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    AppEntry.js:4
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:197:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0

Comment: Please post the actual code (not just the file names and line numbers) around where this error occurs.

Comment: @Slown1970 have you got any answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're using react-redux-firebase version 3 and possibly you are initializing using version 2 method.
Please refer to v3 documents for proper initialization http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/